# Error beanFactory/ApplicationContext - JAVA

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, javabeans, alfresco

I'm following a [tutorial](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/NodeRef_cookbook) to manipulate nodeRef and content on Alfresco with JAVA. But when I try to define the `serviceRegistry`,

```
 ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = (ServiceRegistry) beanFactory.getBean(ServiceRegistry.SERVICE_REGISTRY);
```

the `beanFactory` is not initialized. And I already try much declarations but I can't initialise/declare this correctly. Can anyone help me?

I try:

```
ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("alfresco/web-client-application-context.xml");
```

ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = (ServiceRegistry) appContext.getBean(ServiceRegistry.SERVICE_REGISTRY);

**web-client-application-context.xml**:
https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition/blob/master/projects/web-client/config/alfresco/web-client-application-context.xml

ERROR:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'GlobalAuthenticationFilter' defined in class
> path resource [alfresco/web-client-application-context.xml]: Cannot
> resolve reference to bean 'Authentication' while setting bean property
> 'applicationContextManager'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> bean named 'Authentication' is defined

Another way? How can I solve this?

Comment: [This page](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Java_Foundation_API) suggests you should use `alfresco/application-context.xml` as an app context config, or even better, use Spring dependency injection to get all required service beans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by substitute this:  `ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = (ServiceRegistry) beanFactory.getBean(ServiceRegistry.SERVICE_REGISTRY);`

for this:

```
protected ServiceRegistry getServiceRegistry() {
        ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl config = Context.getProcessEngineConfiguration();
        if (config != null) {
            // Fetch the registry that is injected in the activiti spring-configuration
            ServiceRegistry registry = (ServiceRegistry) config.getBeans().get(ActivitiConstants.SERVICE_REGISTRY_BEAN_KEY);

            if (registry == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Service-registry not present in ProcessEngineConfiguration beans, expected ServiceRegistry with key" + ActivitiConstants.SERVICE_REGISTRY_BEAN_KEY);
            }

            return registry;
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("No ProcessEngineCOnfiguration found in active context");
    }
```